# Telling javac to ignore System.out.println()

Tags: java, javac

i'm using System.out.println() (sout) for debugging and general state overview purposes while programming (which is especially helpful for network stuff). Since i want my code to be efficient at the end, is there a way to tell the java compiler to ignore souts?

I already tried some googling, but the solutions where very unsatisfying, like putting all souts inside an if with a global variable. (Tripling the lines and making code very unreadable if a lot of souts are needed)

Anyone know if such a compiler option exists (if not, why not?), or if there is some other more elegant solution then the one stated above. Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: In general, you should be using a logging framework rather than `System.out.println()`. That gives you much more granular control and, in some frameworks, avoids performance and memory hits of string concatenations for unused log statements.

Comment: This answer probably isn't what you are looking for, but you could write your own `println` function, and then when you are compiling it for real, you just make it empty.

Comment: +1 to using a logging framework.  Alternatively If your program runs in its own jvm, you can just change `System.out`.  It's just a PrintStream, so you could set it to a PrintStream that throws away input.  The side effect, of course, is that *everything* that writes to System.out in that copy of the JVM will get ignored.

Comment: I'm going to reiterate what @Palpatim said. Use a logging framework. If you want a  specific recommendation, I'd go with SLF4J and Logback. It comes with No-op, Console and File loggers, and if you use something like Maven to build your project you can use profiles to configure which logger to use in certain cases. In our case we use a Console logger for local development and a File one for all other scenarios. Further more only test environments use the DEBUG log level. Production code uses ERROR.

Comment: Why don't you wrap System.out.println() in a utility method which only outputs to console based upon a system property passed e.g. -DoutputToConsole=true. This should only be considered if you cannot use a logging framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**logging**](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html). You can indicate a log level that normally won't be displayed, and with logging properties can be made to appear. This can be done controlled etc.

```
Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.FINE, "...");
```

In fact there are many examples and aspects to logging. So if you want your code to be minimalistic but mature, use logging.

An alternative way would be to use **unit tests**, and to not output in the production code. This requires more strictness and allows to find regression errors.

And a third alternative would be to more liberally use (unchecked) **exceptions**, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException. To have an informative fail-fast.

Answer (score 4):

First I would like to say that the real answer to this question is to use a logging framework as others have shown.

But if you are committed to using System.out, you can still achieve the desired effect.  In the below class, I change `System.out` (by using the `System.setOut` method) to another PrintStream that does not actually print anything.

```
import java.io.*;

    class Sys
    {
        public static void main ( String [ ] args ){
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream(){
            @Override
                public void write(int b){
            }
            }));
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

My answer can be improved upon.  For example, it will still convert objects to string for printing, but you can solve that by setting out to an overrided PrintStream class that does absolutely nothing.

But the more you improve upon it, the more you are just implementing a logging utility which someone else has already done.  This is why I suggest logging is the real answer.

Comment: +1 as just what the question asked for. Could check whether `args[i]` would be a "verbose" flag and then not do a `setOut`.

Comment: This one has got my vote too; a  proper logging API is a better architectural design, but this actually answers the question asked in the context of using System.out for logging purposes.